# Count how often the word occurs in the text in PHP

Tags: php

In php I need to Load a file and get all of the words and echo the word and the number of times each word shows up in the text,
(I also need them to show up in descending order most used words on top) ★✩

Comment: is this homework? what do you have so far?

Comment: I haven't started yet just trying to figure out the best aproach

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Here's an example:**

```
$text = "A very nice únÌcÕdë text. Something nice to think about if you're into Unicode.";

// $words = str_word_count($text, 1); // use this function if you only want ASCII
$words = utf8_str_word_count($text, 1); // use this function if you care about i18n

$frequency = array_count_values($words);

arsort($frequency);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($frequency);
echo '</pre>';
```

**The output:**

```
Array
(
    [nice] => 2
    [if] => 1
    [about] => 1
    [you're] => 1
    [into] => 1
    [Unicode] => 1
    [think] => 1
    [to] => 1
    [very] => 1
    [únÌcÕdë] => 1
    [text] => 1
    [Something] => 1
    [A] => 1
)
```

**And the `utf8_str_word_count()` function, if you need it:**

```
function utf8_str_word_count($string, $format = 0, $charlist = null)
{
    $result = array();

    if (preg_match_all('~[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}' . preg_quote($charlist, '~') . ']+~u', $string, $result) > 0)
    {
        if (array_key_exists(0, $result) === true)
        {
            $result = $result[0];
        }
    }

    if ($format == 0)
    {
        $result = count($result);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: beautiful :) for the utf8 support :)

Comment: Instead of making a new question about this i will see if you will repsond to this, I did what you said in your code, this works just as i wanted! However how can I show it within a table with 2 rows: left the word and right the frequency. I hope you understand what i mean!

Comment: @DejaVu: Make a foreach loop that goes through all elements and on each iteration create a `<tr>`, then output the array key on the first column and the key value on the second column. That simple...

Answer (score 3):

```
$words = str_word_count($text, 1);
$word_frequencies = array_count_values($words);
arsort($word_frequencies);
print_r($word_frequencies);
```

Answer (score 2):

This function uses a regex to find words (you might want to change it, depending on what you define a word as)

```
function count_words($text)
{
    $output = $words = array();
    preg_match_all("/[A-Za-z'-]+/", $text, $words); // Find words in the text

    foreach ($words[0] as $word)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($word, $output))
            $output[$word] = 0;

        $output[$word]++; // Every time we find this word, we add 1 to the count
    }

    return $output;
}
```

This iterates over each word, constructing an associative array (with the word as the key) where the value refers to the occurences of each word. (e.g. $output['hello'] = 3 => hello occured 3 times in the text).

Perhaps you might want to change the function to deal with case insensitivity (i.e. 'hello' and 'Hello' are not the same word, according to this function).

Comment: The OP never defined the language the word would be sought in, assuming its a language which uses whitespace in written text yours fails on words that contain umlauts, grave symbols...etc. the use of the regex-canonical "\w" should match only "word characters" which includes Latin letters with accent marks as well as the more exotic ones from Cyrillic, Hangul, Thai, Hindi...etc.

Comment: Thank you so much this answers my question,  But you gave me one more Now I have to study regex - can you tell me how to make hello and Hello the same word.  AND some of the words in the text has
 ĉ ĵ ĝ ĥ ŭ ŝ  in lowercase and caps
 Its in esperanto

Comment: Read Jason D's suggestion, as to recognising all of the words.  To match both cases, you just need to consider what is being compared in the foreach loop (at the moment we use $word as the key to the array, whereas you want the key to be all in the same case - check out php.net/strtolower)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo count(explode('your_word', $your_text));
```

Comment: Is this matching the question ?

Comment: The thing is I want to get a list of the words in descending order,  not count a specific word